# Need a little help

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have a question, suppose that $S_{n+2}=13S_{n+1}+48S_n$.
How do I find a general solution for this recurrence equation and 
how do I find the particular solution where $S_0=1$ and $S_1=5$.

Here is what I've got so far, I brought everything to the left side of the equation to get $x^2-13x-48=0$. Roots are $16$ and $-3$. So to get the general equation, I believe I have to use the roots somewhere such as $S_n=A\cdot16^n-B\cdot3^n$. I know I am probably wrong.

Could someone explain the process how to get the general solution and particular solution?

Comment: You are pretty close, the general solution has the form $S_n = A 16^n + B (\color{red}{-}3)^n$.

Comment: The general solution will have to be of the form $A\cdot16^n + B\cdot(-3)^n$. I'm guessing you meant $48S_n$, not $48S_{n+1}$ in your statement. There are a lot of good descriptions of the underlying methods. Search for how to solve linear recurrence relations... https://www.google.com/search?q=solving+linear+recurrence+relations

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there is a typo in your recurrence relation. Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: LOL good guess by me!!!! Ok, so I can't really read the fine print of the book that well, so after finding the roots, I just plug in the roots for A(r)^n + B(r)^n where A and B are constants?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. And thank you for the link.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/209640/solving-a-recurrence-relation-with-the-characteristic-equation) is the technique.

Comment: Thanks, Mhenni, but I got lost on that one... LOL

Comment: @RichSanchez: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to the homogeneous recurrence is $S_n=A\cdot16^n+B(-3)^n$. You can’t pull the sign out of $(-3)^n$: it’s equal to $(-1)^n\cdot3^n$, not to $-3^n$. No matter what the initial values are, the general term will have the form $S_n=A\cdot16^n+B(-3)^n$: each pair of values for $S_0$ and $S_1$ determines a unique pair of coefficients $A$ and $B$, and vice versa.

To find $A$ and $B$, substitute $n=0$ and $n=1$ into the general solution and use the known values of $S_0$ and $S_1$ to get the system

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&1=A+B\\
&5=16A-3B\;.
\end{align*}\right.$$

To complete the solution, just solve the system to get $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Ok, just for layman's terms. Is the formula to find the solution basically S_n = A(r)^n + B(r)^n where A and B are constants and r is the root of the equation? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Rich: If the characteristic equation has distinct roots $r_1$ and $r_2$, the general solution is $S_n=Ar_1^n+Br_2^n$. If the characteristic equation has a double root $r$ (e.g., $x^2-4x-4=0$, with double root $2$), the general solution is $S_n=Ar^n+Bnr^n=(A+Bn)r^n$.

Comment: Wonderful! You make it so easy to learn... LOL Another question, how do you know when you can't use a root? I remember him writing it in class but i was behind on the notes and still writing from earlier so didn't get to understand it or really see the example. Is there a case when a characteristic equation is factorable but you can't use one of the roots?

Comment: @Rich: You can always use the roots. Is it possible that he was talking about the case of a repeated root $r$ and saying that you can’t write the general solution as $Ar^n+Br^n$, but have to use $Ar^n+Bnr^n$ instead?

Comment: Not sure, he went fast... LOL

Comment: @Rich: That’s the only thing I can think of that might fit. As long as you’re looking at a homogeneous linear recurrence with constant coefficients, you’ll use all of the roots of the characteristic equation. Of course some of them might not be real numbers: you might get complex roots.

Comment: Ok while I'm on a role understanding, can you tell me how from another post, [discrete math](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548503/recurrence-equations-general-solutions) What formula did he use to get that general equation? Not the one you just used for mine, right?

Comment: @Rich: That recurrence is non-homogeneous, so it does require different techniques. It can be solved in a variety of ways, and I can’t guess which one(s) you’ll be shown.

Comment: It's not in the Ar^n + Br_2^n model though? Share the simplest layman's terms to find the general equation for that one.

Comment: @Rich: Take a look at the method used in the example in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/332923/12042). It could be converted to a general formula for this very restricted type of recurrence, but it’s easier just to remember the method.

Comment: Ok thanks. Sorry forgot about this problem. So how do I get a particular solution from here?

Comment: @Rick: I’m not sure what you mean here by *particular equation*.

Comment: Sorry meant particular solution...

Comment: @Rich: The general solution is $S_n=A\cdot16^n+B(-3)^n$, and you’ve now found $A$ and $B$, so all you have to do is plug them in to the general solution. However, you need to check your work in your solution of the system: you got $A$ upside down and then calculated $B$ from that incorrect value of $A$.

Comment: OK.. LOL thanks... will work on it now and show if what I got...

Comment: S_n = (8/19)16^n + 11/19(-3)^n?

Comment: @Rich: Yes, that looks much better.

Comment: Ok, thank you much! I can sleep well tonight... LOL

Comment: @Rich: You’re welcome! Get some sleep. :-)